# Can the 'r' be removed from a function stack

Tags: ida

Original question asked on Stackoverflow: [Can the 'r' be removed from a function stack ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976139/can-the-r-be-removed-from-a-function-stack)

I am trying to modify the processor for the Fujitsu FR, and IDA by default inserts the return variable `r` on each stack, but the Fujitsu FR processor does not put `r` as the first item, so this stuffs up the stack.

What I can't workout is: in the processor plugin, what needs overriding to resolve this, or if any of the example processors have solutions to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for completeness, implementing `get_frame_retsize` [`int (*get_frame_retsize(func_t *pfn)`] in your `processor_t LPH` is the solution to this.

in that function for my processor I needed to return zero instead of the default of 4.